# Split Access Database - Issues with backend

Tags: database, ms-access, backend

I created and deployed a split access database in Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, however every time a user opens the front end file it opens the temporary file that locks the backend as well - defeating the purpose of splitting the database in the first place. Anyone else have issues with this? The backend file is never actually opened - it should just be relaying information to the frontend file...

This was tested in a folder that allowed full permissions for all users.

Comment: Yes, the locked file would generate as the backend is any other Access file enabling a multiple user environment and so sets its optimistic record locking on the linked tables. Users can still get into backend, just not design changes (but how often does tables changes get made after deployment). See benefits of [split systems](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-plus-reasons-to-split-an-access-database/).

Comment: The .laccdb/.ldb lock file contains the record locking information for the database. It does not indicate file level locking! Did you actually try to edit records in the backend with multiple users at a time?

Comment: I tried to edit the records however I got the record lock error just upon entering the front end with 2 active users